# for this matrix find charactristic and minimal polynomials and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 9 \\1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the charpoly which is $\lambda^2-4\lambda-21$ and eigenvalues are $7$ and $-3$ but I am not sure how to construct next the minimal polynomial.  This is not in the book and I am not sure how to construct this one.

Comment: Do you know that the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial have the same irreducible factors?

Comment: The minimal polynomial for a matrix $A$ is "smallest" polynomial which vanishes when you put in $A$. Note that $(\lambda +3)(\lambda -7)$ is a good guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  How to you put in $A$?  When I put this in I get matrix of first row zeroes and second row ones.  So it DNE??

Comment: Think of it as $(A + 3I)(A - 7I)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: perhaps my calculation is not correct I will try once more.  Edit: yes it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Since $(A + 3I)(A- 7I) = 0$, you know that the minimal polynomial DIVIDES $(\lambda + 3)(\lambda - 7)$. This doesn't immediately tell you that the minimal polynomial IS $(\lambda + 3)(\lambda - 7)$. You also need to check that $A + 3I \neq 0$ and $A - 7I \neq 0$.

Comment: ... though in practice, this isn't necessary, since it can be proven that the minimal polynomial of any matrix has the same set of irreducible factors as the characteristic polynomial. Since the irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial here are $\lambda + 3$ and $\lambda - 7$, the minimal polynomial MUST be $(\lambda + 3)(\lambda - 7)$.